# Replace pattern in an existing line using sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace the

```
/fdasatavol/ankit
```

to

```
/fdasatavol_sata/ankit
```

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Basic `echo "/fdasatavol/ankit" | sed 's/fdasatavol/fdasatavol_sata/'` will work, but it seems to me you want something more generic. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

to write to a new file (without modifying file1):

```
sed 's/fdasatavol/fdasatavol_sata/g' file1 > file2
```

or to replace in the original file:

```
sed -i 's/fdasatavol/fdasatavol_sata/g' file1
```

Comment: this would hit all cases of fdasatavol which might include others not desired which have a different context.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace each occurrence of `fdasatavol` with `fdasatavol_sata`:

```
sed 's/fdasatavol/&_sata/g'
```

If your input has occurrence of `fdasatavol` that are not in `/fdasatavol/ankit` and you don't want to substitute these then use:

```
sed 's@/fdasatavol/ankit@/fdastatavol_sata/ankit@g'
```

Note: you can use any character as sed's delimilter to aviod the confusion with the parrtern contiaing `/`. `sed` prints to `stdout` by default, if you are happy with the changes produced by `sed` you can use the `-i` option to store back to the file.

```
sed -i 's/fdasatavol/&_stat/g' file
```

Comment: Props (and +1) for pointing out the safer usage involving the whole pattern to avoid altering other parts of the file